# bar graph project unused method in uiview

Tags: objective-c, methods, uiview

I found in git some bar graph project, that I would like to work with: [here](https://github.com/dhilipsiva/DSBarChart)
The code is pretty simple. The draw object has only 3 methods, like init, calc, and drawRect. 
The funny point is, I can not find the line, that call this method: drawRect. 
I looked in all the classes. It looks to start automatically, but why? How do I know which methods will start automatically, and which not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the [Apple Documentation on `UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCDGJHF)? It specifically states

> This method is called when a view is first displayed or when an event occurs that invalidates a visible part of the view. You should **NEVER** call this method directly yourself. To invalidate part of your view, and thus cause that portion to be redrawn, call the setNeedsDisplay or setNeedsDisplayInRect: method instead.

So you should never actually call that method directly it will get called by the super versions of `setNeedsDisplay` or `setNeedsDisplayInRect`. I have included the whole section of the article below which I would recommend reading.

> The default implementation of this method does nothing. Subclasses that use technologies such as Core Graphics and UIKit to draw their view’s content should override this method and implement their drawing code there. You do not need to override this method if your view sets its content in other ways. For example, you do not need to override this method if your view just displays a background color or if your view sets its content directly using the underlying layer object.
>
> By the time this method is called, UIKit has configured the drawing environment appropriately for your view and you can simply call whatever drawing methods and functions you need to render your content. Specifically, UIKit creates and configures a graphics context for drawing and adjusts the transform of that context so that its origin matches the origin of your view’s bounds rectangle. You can get a reference to the graphics context using the UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext function, but do not establish a strong reference to the graphics context because it can change between calls to the drawRect: method.
>
> Similarly, if you draw using OpenGL ES and the GLKView class, GLKit configures the underlying OpenGL ES context appropriately for your view before calling this method (or the glkView:drawInRect: method of your GLKView delegate), so you can simply issue whatever OpenGL ES commands you need to render your content. For more information about how to draw using OpenGL ES, see OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS.
>
> You should limit any drawing to the rectangle specified in the rect parameter. In addition, if the opaque property of your view is set to YES, your drawRect: method must totally fill the specified rectangle with opaque content.
>
> If you subclass UIView directly, your implementation of this method does not need to call super. However, if you are subclassing a different view class, you should call super at some point in your implementation.
>
> This method is called when a view is first displayed or when an event occurs that invalidates a visible part of the view. You should never call this method directly yourself. To invalidate part of your view, and thus cause that portion to be redrawn, call the setNeedsDisplay or setNeedsDisplayInRect: method instead.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/
```

So only this one Method will be activated automatically.